# webpack-cli Objeto de configuración no válido. Server Mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio

Al momento de correr mi server mock me dispara un error de webpack, aparentemente no encuentra la API

"Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Como se llama el pack que usas para las waifu? saludos

Comment: @g.4 Hola que tal, la extensión se llama, The Doki Theme. La puedes encontrar aquí.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unthrottled.doki-theme

Answer (score 0):

```
 performance:{
        maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
        maxAssetSize: 512000,
    },
```

`points` lo tenia puesto con "P" mayuscula.